# iOS move to segue without adding ViewController to stack

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, viewcontroller

In my application i'm using the navigation controller as an "Action Bar" and in most scenarios there is no Back Icon.

If i understand correctly, when i'm using segues to move to the next screen, iOS keep a reference of my last screen so i will be able to press back and return to it quickly.

can i have the same segue with moving to next screen, but somehow tell the navigation bar not to save an instance of the the last view controller ? i need that in order to avoid duplicate view controllers in the view controllers stack, and to avoid overloading the memory.

Comment: You can't do that with a navigation controller. It's not clear what you mean about avoiding duplicate view controllers on the stack -- each controller on the stack should be a different one, so why would there be duplicates? Do you have many view controllers? You should further explain your app structure.

Comment: his question is pretty clear. When he segues to a view controller it gets added to his navigation stack. He doesn't use 'back' to return to his previous view controller, so when he segues backwards it adds ANOTHER (copy) view controller to his navigation stack. Diagrammed it would look like this:
start w/ vc A (nav stack has A) -> go to vc B (nav stack has A, B) -> return to A (nav stack has A, B, A).